# Search Order sorting in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, xslt

This query returns  data sets.Whenever I try to sort it on corresponding value its working only for a some of the columns and not working for firm ID and jurisdiction.(Pagination is done for 50 values)and for sorting we have  "ORDER BY {OrderBy.Parameters}" clause in query.

and  from xslt we have below piece of code for sorting :

```
<th data-orderby-column="XmlTable.FirmID">
            <xsl:text>Firm ID</xsl:text>
          </th>
          <th data-orderby-column="XmlTable.EIN">
            <xsl:text>EIN</xsl:text>
          </th>
          <th data-orderby-column="Vendor.Organization">
            <xsl:text>Law Firm Name</xsl:text>
          </th>
          <th data-orderby-column="XmlTable.Jurisdiction">
            <xsl:text>Jurisdiction</xsl:text>
          </th>
          <th data-orderby-column="CreatedDate">
            <xsl:text>No Objection Date</xsl:text>
          </th>
```

and the statement for select and sort is :

```
<Statement Name="SearchSATS" Transform="{Table}.Search.xslt" Query="
    DECLARE @Count int;
    DECLARE @XmlTable TABLE (RowNumber int IDENTITY(0,1), IdentityID int, FirmID nvarchar(50), FirmStatus nvarchar(50), Jurisdiction nvarchar(50), TrainingCompletion datetime, EIN nvarchar(50), ContractCreatedPerson nvarchar(255));
    INSERT INTO @XmlTable (IdentityID, FirmID, FirmStatus, Jurisdiction, TrainingCompletion, EIN, ContractCreatedPerson)
    SELECT TOP (@Batch) {Table}.{Table}ID ,
      (SELECT TOP 1 CollectionMember.CollectionMember FROM CollectionMember WITH (NOLOCK) INNER JOIN Collection WITH (NOLOCK) ON Collection.CollectionID = CollectionMember.CollectionID
               WHERE Collection.Collection = 'LMWS ID' AND  CollectionMember.SourceObjectID = ImportForm.AssignedOrganizationID),
      CASE
          WHEN Contract.ContractID IS NULL THEN 'GSE Contract Required'
          WHEN Training.VerifiedDate IS NOT NULL AND Contract.Status  = 'LRA Executed' THEN 'No Objection - Notified'
          WHEN Training.VerifiedDate IS NOT NULL AND Contract.Status &lt;&gt; 'LRA Executed' THEN 'Training Complete'
          WHEN Contract.Status  = 'LRA Executed' THEN 'GSE Contract Signed'
          WHEN Contract.Status  = 'LRA Sent' THEN 'GSE Contract Sent'
          WHEN Contract.Status  = 'LRA Received' THEN 'GSE Contract Received'
          ELSE 'GSE Contract Required'
      END,
      CONVERT(xml, XmlData).value('(/ImportFormXml/AssignedOrganization_Regions_0_State)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)') ,
      (SELECT TOP 1 VerifiedDate FROM Contact WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE ObjectID = Contract.VendorID AND Contact.Object = 'Organization' AND Contact.ContactType = 'Training'),
      Contact.TIN,
      (SELECT Person FROM Person WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE PersonID = Contract.CreatedPersonID)
    FROM {From.ForeignKey} 
    INNER JOIN Contact WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON  Contact.ContactID = Vendor.ContactID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact Training WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  Training.Object = 'Organization' 
            AND Training.ObjectID = Vendor.OrganizationID 
            AND Training.ContactType = 'Training'   
      INNER JOIN ObjectLink WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON  ObjectLink = 'LRA Contract Form Link'
                  AND ObjectLink.PrimaryObjectID = Contract.ContractID
                  AND ObjectLink.PrimaryObject = 'Contract'
                  AND ObjectLink.LinkedObject = 'ImportForm'
      INNER JOIN ImportForm WITH (NOLOCK)
          ON    ImportForm.ImportFormID = ObjectLink.LinkedObjectID 
    WHERE {Where.Basic} AND {Where.Filters} 
      AND (@FirmStatus IS NULL OR @FirmStatus = 
                                    CASE
                        WHEN Contract.ContractID IS NULL THEN 'GSE Contract Required'
                        WHEN Training.VerifiedDate IS NOT NULL AND Contract.Status  = 'LRA Executed' THEN 'No Objection - Notified'
                        WHEN Training.VerifiedDate IS NOT NULL AND Contract.Status &lt;&gt; 'LRA Executed' THEN 'Training Complete'
                        WHEN Contract.Status  = 'LRA Executed' THEN 'GSE Contract Signed'
                        WHEN Contract.Status  = 'LRA Sent' THEN 'GSE Contract Sent'
                        WHEN Contract.Status  = 'LRA Received' THEN 'GSE Contract Received'
                        ELSE 'GSE Contract Required'
                   END
       )
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ImportForm WITH (NOLOCK) 
                WHERE AssignedOrganizationID = Contract.VendorID
                AND CONVERT(xml, XmlData).value('(/ImportFormXml/QuestionContractYesNo)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') = 'Yes'
        AND ImportForm.Status = 'Reviewed'
        AND ImportForm.ImportFormType = 'No Objection'
                )

     ORDER BY {OrderBy.Parameters}

    SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT
    IF @DisplaySize = 0 SET @DisplaySize = @Count

    SELECT {Select.ForeignKeyLabel},

        @Count AS RecordCount,
      XmlTable.Jurisdiction,
      XmlTable.FirmID,
      XmlTable.TrainingCompletion,
      XmlTable.FirmStatus
    FROM {From.ForeignKey}
    INNER JOIN @XmlTable XmlTable ON XmlTable.IdentityID = {Table}.{Table}ID
    WHERE
       XmlTable.RowNumber BETWEEN @RecordStart AND (@RecordStart + @DisplaySize - 1)
      ORDER BY
      XmlTable.RowNumber
            ">
           <Parameters>
        <Parameter Name="Batch" DbType="Int32" Value="50000"/>
        <Parameter Name="FirmStatus" DbType="String"/>

      </Parameters>
    </Statement>
```